# Miller-Rabin test–selecting a particular $a$

Tags: number-theory

In Miller-Rabin test, for $a\mod p$, we select $a$ in the range $1<a<p-1$ in the process of proving that $p$ is prime. Now, I'm confused, if any  integer that falls in this range will satisfy the test? Or, will at least one integer in the given range satisfy the test(that p is inconclusive to be prime)? Please explain the reason as well

Comment: Not every $a$ will necessarily work, but at least 75% of them will.

Comment: for primes, shouldn't every a work? I mean, what's the use of the theorem then? And the theorem state select any random a, and we do the test once and conclude? That's pretty...un-mathematical?

Comment: I'm sorry, I've misread the question. Yes, for $p$ prime every prime will work, while for $p$ composite 75% of $a$ will show $p$ is not prime. This is why it's a probabilistic test - if you choose randomly, you know with at least 75% certainty that the answer is correct. If you repeat it more times with different $a$, you can get higher certainty.

Comment: for p prime, every prime will work? or, did you mean every $a$ would work?

Comment: Yes, I meant $a$.

Comment: I don't know if i'd made any mistake, but it doesn't quite seem to work for a=2 and p=13?

Comment: We check $2^{12}\equiv 1\pmod{13}$ and $2^6\equiv-1\pmod{13}$. Since the first non-1 term is $-1$, we output "prime".

Comment: oops, I was miscalculating. BTW, how does the 75% chance come to be?

Comment: Check out [this article](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/ugradnumthy/millerrabin.pdf)